# Removing line breaks from log files

Tags: files, text-processing, file-format

I'm trying to extract some information from a log file and need to remove the line breaks from it, in order to handle it easily, here is an example of the needed result :

input file :

```
02/01/2018 08:18:14      ANR0407I Session 63121 started for administrator 
                         ADMIN_CENTER (DSMAPI) (Tcp/Ip SAP-DOC(52499)).SESSION: 
                         63121)
```

Output should be :

```
02/01/2018 08:18:14      ANR0407I Session 63121 started for administrator ADMIN_CENTER (DSMAPI) (Tcp/Ip SAP-DOC(52499(SESSION: 63121)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed` to join lines to the previous one if they start with a sequence of blank (space or horizontal tab) characters:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' file.log
```

This is a minor variation of the example **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "="** from [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/)

---

If the 'blocks' are separated by one or more blank lines (you don't show enough of the log to know whether this is the case) then a simpler alternative would be to use `awk` in *paragraph mode*:

```
awk -vRS= '{$1=$1} 1' file.log
```

which reads in whole paragraphs and then re-formats them with the default (single space) output separator.

Comment: It looks much better, however it's adding extra characters `^M` 

example of output :

`02/02/2018 08:32:37      ANR4930I Reclamation process 1343 started for primary     ^M storage pool VM_VTL_POOL automatically, threshold=75,    ^M duration=None. (PROCESS: 1343) `

Comment: @AzizAzizos what method are you using to view the logs? The `sed` command itself would not add such characters - however they may be carriage returns from the original log file (indicating that it was saved with DOS-style CRLF line endings). If that's the case, try replacing `\n` by `\r\n` in the sed expression.